# Parameterised string issue in android app

Tags: android, localization, chinese-locale

I have a android app in which I am adding localisation support. I have a string with parameter in my xml file .

```
<string name="str_x_seconds">%1$d seconds</string>
```

String value in Chinese language "

```
 <string name="str_x_seconds">％1$d秒</string>
```

When I am using my app in Chinese language , it is not "％1$d秒" instead of parameterised text.

I am using like this :

```
String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.str_x_seconds),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(vyn.getDuration()));
```

Any help please?

Comment: Add one space after %1$d. It should be `％1$d 秒`.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols '%' and '％' are different, check their codes to be sure here:

http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html

Please, use the '%' symbol with code 37.